# In Homeworld, was their solar system under surveillance?

Tags: video-games, homeworld

Khar-Selim was deployed to assist and resupply the mothership, soon after it was deployed, they were attacked and destroyed by the Turanic Raiders which seemed to be under control of the Taidan fleet.

It seems that soon after Kharak made it's oficial space program, they were detected and tracked. It doesn't seems to be a mere coincidence. First they attacked Khar-Selim, and soon after, they bombed they planet and tried to destroy the cryo trays. So, were they under surveilance? And why?

Answer (score 2):

As noted in canonical backstory, when the Higaarans were exiled by the Taidaan, they were also forbidden from developing hyperdrive technology, with the punishment being the destruction of their world.  While the treaty had been forgotten from public consciousness, the technical portion of the Taidaan military still recalled this, and when the hyperdrive test was detected, they sent a fleet to Kharak and killed all the life on it (which then resulted in the formation of the Taidaan rebellion).

Comment: Did you know that they are going to sell a remastered collection and that the collectors edition has a small replica of the mothership? I WANT ONE!!!

Comment: Huh, I knew about the remastered collection (the videos look quite nice), but hadn't heard about the Mothership replica.

Comment: I need to buy this!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, nevermind. I've found the answer [here](http://youtu.be/CXNQNeLDg5s?t=7m26s). The people at Kharak violated a 4000 years old law that forbids them to develop hyperspace technology.